# Create a flexible database in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to create a database recording car crashed per street in PostgreSQL. The database should have the following entries:
Date Range, Street Name, Crash
The date range simply stores the date range so f.e. from 2020-01-01 until 2020-01-05
The street name the name of the street
And crash is TRUE if a crash happened in that street during that date range and FALSE if not.

I now have a pandas.dataframe of data with these information and want to upload it via a python script into the psql database.

I want to achieve two things:
For example from 2020-01-01 until 2020-04-03 there was no crash on street xyz. Then I only want one entry in the database for that timeframe looking like

```
[2020-01-01, 2020-04-03],xyz,FALSE
```

But it could happen that later I discover there actually was a car crash on the street during that timeframe, say on 2020-02-10
Then I would like to split up this entry into the following three

```
[2020-01-01, 2020-02-09],xyz,FALSE
[2020-02-10],xyz,TRUE
[2020-02-11, 2020-04-03],xyz,FALSE
```

Ideally, if I run the simulation only for 2020-02-10 the database would recognize that this date is in an existing timeframe and would split up the timeframe around this date.

Similarly, if I would run the simulation from 2020-02-01 until 2020-03-01 the program should realize that this is also in an existing timeframe already but still produce the outcome

```
[2020-01-01, 2020-02-09],xyz,FALSE  
[2020-02-10],xyz,TRUE
[2020-02-11, 2020-04-03],xyz,FALSE
```

Edit:
So my question would be: How can I create such a database and a python script loading the data into it.

Comment: Ok, you've described your objective, but you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Why don't you store a car crash with its date and query and aggregate over that data?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular
My question is how can I create such a database and a script loading the data into it in this way.

Comment: @KlausD. What do you mean by that? Sorry, I am new to psql & database in general.

Comment: You form of intermediate data (timeframe + boolean) is hard to query. It is better to have data in a raw form. If you have the data of every crash stored, you can easily query for a data range but not the other way around.

Comment: @KlausD. So the dataframe has the events by the date meaning
[day1,street,crash],[day2,street,crash] etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your data model should be improved. It seems that you plan to have only a single table in the database that stores the information exactly in the way you are planning to display the results.

You should have at least two tables, one for the streets and one for the crashes, where the latter contains a foreign key to the former.

Then, I would start with an empty tables for the crashes and add an entry for each crash.

The date ranges without crash can easily be calculated when you query the database, and there is no need to persist them.  That will save you the headache of splitting ranges when new data come in.